# General question on the test and train data

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model

Currently I'm working on a Kaggle problem. I have to predict an outcome by the given information. There are few metafiles for training a model with lots of features (>30). However, in the test file none of this features are presented. May be I misunderstand something, but how can the other features (not presented in a test validation) help us to train a better model?

Comment: Can you link the Kaggle problem? It sounds like there is some misunderstanding, but without having a look on my own, I can not be sure.

Comment: By "test file", do you actually mean a "submission file"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.